# DataTables pagination from material-ui not working

Tags: reactjs, datatable, pagination, material-ui

I have defined a table that shows some recommended products:

```
<DataTables
     height={'auto'}
     selectable={false}
     showRowHover={true}
     columns={RECOMMENDED_TABLE_COLUMNS}
     data={this.state.products}
     showCheckboxes={false}
     rowSizeLabel="Filas por página"
     page={1}
     rowSize={10}
     rowSizeList={[10,20,30,50]}
       />
```

The table that is called is the following:

```
const RECOMMENDED_TABLE_COLUMNS = [
    {
        key: 'name',
        label: 'Producto',
        style:{width: '65%'}
    }, {
        key: 'price',
        label: 'Precio del producto',
        style:{width: '35%'},
        render: (amount) => {
            return amount + ' ' + currencyToAppend;
        }
    }
];
```

The data comes from this function:

```
getProducts(){
        fetch(
            DOMAIN+'/api/products/', {
                method: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization':'Bearer '+this.props.token
                }
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                responseData.map((value)=>{
                    if(value.brand)value.brand=value.brand.name;
                    if(value.price)value.priceFormatted=value.price.toFixed(2).toString().replace('.',',')+' €';
                    return true;
                });
                this.setState({products:responseData})
            })
            .catch(function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            });
    }
```

Which is called in:

```
handleCellClick(y,x,row){
        this.setState({
            open:true,
            slideIndex: 0,
            newForm:false,
            customer:{...row}
        });
        this.getProfiles();
        this.getHistory();
        this.getProducts();
    }
```

I am able to print all the products that I want within the table:

[image]

The problem comes when I want to paginate it, showing 10 products per page it just shows all the products from the database:

[image]

The package that I am using is the following: [MATERIAL-UI PACKAGE](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-datatables)

What am I doing wrong? Have I forsaken any property inside DataTables?

EDIT FOR @abdul:

[image]

Next and previous page work when I click the arrows, but there is not any change; it continues displaying all the 72 results from the DB in a single page.

Capture zooming out (the capture is from the bottom of the list, but I can scroll up to the top, showing the rest of the results):

[image]

Comment: @bennygenel It is mentioned at the end of the question, with a link.

Answer (score 4):

I think the reason it's not showing the specific selected number of rows is in the way you're rendering the rows.
The pagination and the table aren't connected, check the documentation demo code in details :

```
        <TableBody>
          {rows.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage).map(row => (
            <TableRow key={row.id}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.name}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
          {emptyRows > 0 && (
            <TableRow style={{ height: 48 * emptyRows }}>
              <TableCell colSpan={6} />
            </TableRow>
          )}
        </TableBody>
```

row.slice is meant to resize the number of rows depending on your pagination.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You are giving it a fixed `page=1` that's always going to be on page 1. Instead define a page in your initial state  like

```
this.state = {
      page: 1
};
```

Then you should make use of the `onNextPageClick` and `onPreviousPageClick` properties.

Ideally your component should look like this

```
class MyTable extends Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

     this.handlePreviousPageClick = this.handlePreviousPageClick.bind(this);
     this.handleNextPageClick = this.handleNextPageClick.bind(this);

      this.state = {
         page: 1
      };
   }

handlePreviousPageClick() {
    var currentPage = this.state.page
    this.setState({
      page: currentPage-1,
    });
  }

  handleNextPageClick() {
    var currentPage = this.state.page
    this.setState({
      page: currentPage + 1,
    });
}

//other handlers 
<DataTables
     page={this.state.page}
     onNextPageClick={this.handleNextPageClick}
     onPreviousPageClick={this.handlePreviousPageClick} 
     //the properties you already have
               />
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try this and post some feedback.

Comment: yeah try it out and let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: I've tried your solution. Now arrows work, changing the number of the results that should be displayed, but the list doesn't change showing all the time the 72 results from the DB. I've posted a capture at the end of the question.

Comment: Does it display all the 72 pages on 1 page or it just shows 10 rows per page and then doesn't change the data when page changes.

Comment: It displays 72 rows (1 for each product if I'm not mistaken) in a single page. I've added a second capture for you at the end of the question.

Comment: Try setting `count` property to 72  like `count={72}`or initialize it as a state and change it whenever you add a product. Then add the following properties they are self explanatory 
`onRowSizeChange={this.onRowSizeChange}`
  `rowSize={10}`

Comment: I've added the `count` property, `onRowSizeChange` and `rowSize`, and nothing has changed. Any suggestion?

Comment: it's been a while this i used this package i don't use it anymore , i remember facing all kinds of issues. anyways the pagination thing is a bit tricky  take a look at the code provided here https://github.com/hyojin/material-ui-datatables/issues/6 and also a demo by the developer himself https://github.com/hyojin/material-ui-datatables/blob/gh-pages/demo/src/Main.js

Comment: Do not worry, and thanks for your help :) I'll check your links.

Comment: one more thing  don't forgot to mark it as an answer or an upvote. good luck

Answer (score 1):

On https://material-ui.com/components/tables/ page they give

```
<TablePagination
    rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 25, 100]}
    component="div"
    count={rows.length}
    rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
    page={page}
    onPageChange={handleChangePage}
    onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
  />
```

Just change the last 2 lines to

```
onChangePage={handleChangePage}
onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
```